# Body of notifications not showing up JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I made a live chat script and when the user sends a message it should show a notification, although it does show the notification it does not show the body of the notification. Here is my code:

```js
            $(document).ready(function () {
            function askNotificationPermission() {
                   function handlePermission(permission) {
                     if(Notification.permission === 'denied' || Notification.permission === 'default') {
                       alert("You denied notification access");
                     } else {
                     }
                   }
                 
                   if (!('Notification' in window)) {
                     console.log("This browser does not support notifications.");
                   } else {
                     if(checkNotificationPromise()) {
                       Notification.requestPermission()
                       .then((permission) => {
                         handlePermission(permission);
                       })
                     } else {
                       Notification.requestPermission(function(permission) {
                         handlePermission(permission);
                       });
                     }
                   }
                 }
                 function checkNotificationPromise() {
                     try {
                       Notification.requestPermission().then();
                     } catch(e) {
                       return false;
                     }
                     return true;
                 }
                $("#submitmsg").click(function () {
                    var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
                    $.post("post.php", { text: clientmsg });
                    $("#usermsg").val("");
                    var img = "../../images/icon.png";
                    var notofication = new Notification("Chat", { body: clientmsg, icon: img }); 
                    return false;
                });
                function loadLog() {
                    var oldscrollHeight = $("#chatbox")[0].scrollHeight - 20;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "log.html",
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(html) {
                            $("#chatbox").html(html);
                            var newscrollHeight = $("#chatbox")[0].scrollHeight - 20;
                            if(newscrollHeight > oldscrollHeight){
                                $("#chatbox").animate({ scrollTop: newscrollHeight }, 'normal');
                            }   
                        }
                    });
                }
                setInterval(loadLog, 200);
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="usermsg" placeholder="Type something..."/> <button id="submitmsg">Send</button>
```

It does show the notification but does not show the body of notification, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, are you using any plugin ? What does `new Notification("Chat", { ..` refer to ?

Comment: @Swati No plugins just using jQuery AJAX and PHP.

Comment: Can you give [MCVE] ?

Comment: @Swati I gave the code needed to create a notification?

Comment: Yes and it would be good if you can make it runnable .

Comment: @Swati my code contains PHP code that has to be run and snippets can't run PHP but I'll try to.